# How to use `grm` in `ltm` package?

Tags: r

I'm trying to run `grm` in `ltm` package. My script is as follows:

```
library (ltm)
library (msm)
library (polycor)

dim(data)
head(data)
str(data)
descript(data)

options(max.print=1000000) 
rcor.test(data, method = "pearson")

data_2 <- data
data_2[] <- lapply(data_2, factor)
out <- grm(data_2)
out2 <- grm(data_2, constrained = TRUE)
anova(out2,out)

 margins(out)
```

However, when I run `margins(out)` I get this error:  `Error in exp[ind] <- n * colSums(GHw * pp) : subscript out of bounds`

Would someone please explain this? And how can I resolve this?

I have 35 items in my questionnaire and 576 responders. Here is is an example of the data (first 6 responders and first 6 items).

```
  pespd_qa1 pespd_qa2 pespd_qa3 pespd_qa4 pespd_qa5 pespd_qa6 
1         9         5         7         4         1         3                 
2         5         0         9         6         0         8                  
3         5         3         5         6         3         5                  
4         7         5         4         3         1         1                  
5         2         3         0         0         0         0                  
6        10         1         8         2         2         5
```

Comment: Check what kind of objects `margins` accepts and what kind `grm` outputs.

Comment: Do you mean by putting in the command `?margin` and `?grm` ?

Comment: Using those commands, you will be taken to the help pages for those functions. See their inputs/outputs and what objects arguments require. My guess would be that you're feeding `margins` an object which is not compatible.